# Cause of CloudKit Dashboard error "Sorry, we could not process your request"?

Tags: ios, dashboard, cloudkit

I have had this "Sorry, we could not process your request" now for a week when trying to access the CloudKit dashboard.

It occurs when I go to the dashboard from the link in Xcode, after I have entered my login credentials.

CloudKit itself is working fine as my App can sync with existing data and write new data.

Is this a problem for everyone at the moment? Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround, which is to login to my developer account separately at https://developer.apple.com/ and then try the CloudKit Dashboard link again.